# Transforming Slick Streaming data and sending Chunked Response using Akka Http

Tags: scala, akka, slick, akka-stream, akka-http

The aim is to stream data from a database, perform some computation on this chunk of data(this computation returns a Future of some case class) and send this data as chunked response to the user. Currently I am able to stream data and send the response without performing any computation. However, I am unable to perform this computation and then stream the result.

This is the route I have implemented.

```
def streamingDB1 =
path("streaming-db1") {
  get {
    val src = Source.fromPublisher(db.stream(getRds))
    complete(src)
  }
}
```

The function getRds returns the rows of a table mapped into a case class(Using slick). Now consider the function compute which takes each row as an input and returns a Future of another case class. Something like

```
def compute(x: Tweet) : Future[TweetNew] = ?
```

How can I implement this function on variable **src** and send the chunked response(as a stream) of this computation to the user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could transform the source using [`mapAsync`](https://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/stream/scaladsl/Source.html#mapAsync[T](parallelism:Int)(f:Out=>scala.concurrent.Future[T]):FlowOps.this.Repr[T]):

```
val src =
  Source.fromPublisher(db.stream(getRds))
        .mapAsync(parallelism = 3)(compute)

complete(src)
```

Adjust the level of parallelism as needed.

---

Note that you might need to configure a few settings as mentioned in the [Slick documentation](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/dbio.html#streaming):

> Note: Some database systems may require session parameters to be set in a certain way to support streaming without caching all data at once in memory on the client side. For example, PostgreSQL requires both `.withStatementParameters(rsType = ResultSetType.ForwardOnly, rsConcurrency = ResultSetConcurrency.ReadOnly, fetchSize = n)` (with the desired page size `n`) and `.transactionally` for proper streaming.

So if you're using PostgreSQL, for example, then your `Source` might look something like the following:

```
val src =
  Source.fromPublisher(
    db.stream(
      getRds.withStatementParameters(
        rsType = ResultSetType.ForwardOnly,
        rsConcurrency = ResultSetConcurrency.ReadOnly,
        fetchSize = 10
      ).transactionally
    )
  ).mapAsync(parallelism = 3)(compute)
```

Comment: This does not work. I run the curl command to hit the endpoint. However the connection gets closed.

Comment: @user3294786 sounds like it's not properly waiting for data before closing

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik likely is onto something here; I suggest adding a .log() stage to see the elements are actually being sent as expected (and not just a completion), make sure to set akka.loglevel = DEBUG as well

Comment: @user3294786: You marked this as the answer. So has it worked for you now?

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik Yes it worked. I tried this on a different dataset and it worked perfectly. Need to debug why it was failing earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a way to marshall TweetNew and also if you send a chunk with length 0 client may close connection.

This code works with curl:

```
case class TweetNew(str: String)

def compute(string: String) : Future[TweetNew] = Future {
  TweetNew(string)
}

val route = path("hello") {
  get {
    val byteString: Source[ByteString, NotUsed] = Source.apply(List("t1", "t2", "t3"))
      .mapAsync(2)(compute)
      .map(tweet => ByteString(tweet.str + "\n"))
    complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/plain(UTF-8)`, byteString))
  }
}
```

Comment: "f you send a chunk with length 0 client may close connection." -- I believe that Akka is clever enough to filter these out of the stream for you, as they are not representable as HTTP Chunks.